# How to get poisition of the FooterView (or the last item) of a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to get the position of the FooterView (or say the last item in the list) of a `ListView`

I tried `getListView().getCount()` but it hasn't helped.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, but if you have one footer this will get its index:

```
int position = getListView().getCount() - 1;
```